# Excel VBA - Find first instance of value after another value

Tags: vba, excel, extract, vlookup

The example is created to help illustrate my problem.

I have a table of values the following table in Excel:

```
      A                 B         C         D 
Total Inventory      £55,000            Customer 3
Work In Progress     £20,000
Completed Goods      £35,000

Total Inventory      £60,000            Customer 4
Work In Progress     £30,000
Completed Goods      £30,000

Total Inventory      £20,000            Customer 2
Work In Progress     £5,000
Completed Goods      £15,000

Total Inventory      £2000              Customer 1
Work In Progress     £1500
Completed Goods      £500
```

When the table is generated the customers in column D (and the corresponding information in the other columns) appear in a random order. I'd like to extract the "Total Inventory" figure for Customer 4. As such I am wooking for a way to search for "Customer 4" in Column D and then extract the first "Total Inventory" figure which occurs in Coloumn A after that.

I know how to do a VLookup using VBA and extract the figure from Column B but I don't known how to make sure that I extract the correct "Total Inventory" figure when the order of the customers changes each time the table is generated.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Is the Customer in column D appear only once and not on all rows? is the total inventory always the first out of worked in progress and complete goods? It seems like double lookup with index and match will go for you.

Comment: Like I mentioned, the example above is not exactly what I am facing. The code I am using works for now as it simply searches a large range of cells which the value I wish to look up is normally found. In the future the value may move outwith this range or may change position entirely if another customer as added to the spreadsheet (outwith my control). In an effort to future proof my macro I am wondering if there's any way to search by customer first and then search again for "Inventory" beneath that. Posting my current VLookup code would not help progress towards a solution I don't feel

Comment: Thanks Balinti. Yes, the customer in D appears only once and not on all rows. Total inventory could be anywhere within about 200 cells beneath the first one associated with a particular customer. I have been asked to automate a process by my boss and am not particularly clued up on Excel VBA - what would a double lookup wuth index and match look like?

Comment: lol when I said show some code, I meant code towards your new issue, not vlookup. You've been here long enough to know you can't just ask a question without showing any effort towards solving it XD

Comment: If the customer ID appears only once then the most important thing is to populate all of the rows that relevant to this customer. Otherwise you cannot tell (even by eye) which category belong to which customer. Is it populated each time with one customer? If not, is the next line with customer Id suggest that from this row and on that will be the same customer until another row with customer will be populated?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. At the moment everything below "Customer 2" will be associated with that customer until the next "Customer" is reached. That is how the file is provided to me but I can alter it so that the appropriate customer is displayed in every cell of column D

Comment: OK, alter your data and tell me if my answer works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim cust As String

cust = "Customer 3" ' it can be any other varible I just used this to check the data


formu = "index(b:b,match(""" & cust & "Total Inventory"",c:c&a:a,0),1)" ' this one will run to lookups and make sure that correct line with 2 lookup values
Result = Evaluate(formu)
MsgBox (Result) ' again I entered this just to see that this is working


End Sub
```

Text inline. Tested and validated.